# AWS RDS as External Hive Metastore for AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-emr

I have created a AWS RDS instance of MySQL type and want this instance to use as a external hive metastore for EMR.I am creating a EMR and setting the property in "edit software setting" for external hive metastore but getting some errors like"terminating bootstrap failure". Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Also Try to read this aws forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=236894

Comment: Potential duplicate with [External hive metastore for EMR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301995/external-hive-metastore-for-emr)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this Configuration in Edit Software Settings Tab :

`[{"classification":"hive-site","properties":{"javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName":<YOUR_MYSQL_USER>,"javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName":"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword":<YOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD>,"javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL":<YOUR_CONNECTION_URL>}}]`

Thanks

Comment: Try reading this https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=236894

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a EMR cluster with default hive meta store , after which i am overriding the hive-site.xml with some property which are pointing the aws rds instance as hive metastore , everything is fine , but after restarting the hive server , i am not able to use RDS as hive metastore. It is still usin the default hive metastore created by EMR.